# How to make a strings to hold a marionette?

Tags: rigid-body-simulation

I want to make a marionette with strings holding its elbows and hands

Any idea how I can make a rope threads for this dummy?

(I want them to be attached to his arms with notch and have no Idea how to do that...)

[image]

Like this:
[image]
But I want to make strings attached via notches not metal rings like shown here

Comment: Please can you clarify what you're trying to do here - are you looking to create a ragdoll marionette, with strings to hold up and/or attach to the joints. If so then one solution could be to use Rigid Body Constraints to 'pin' the doll to a control rig and then use Soft Body between the pins for the 'ropes'. By carefully tuning the constraints (which would control the distances between the 'pinned' points) and the soft body lengths you should be able to quite convincingly fake the effect of the strings 'holding up' the doll.

Comment: Yes I want to make a marionette with strings holding it' s elbows and hands

Comment: Please show us more examples of what you would like.